# Passing form data between 2 seperate views without carrying it via URL arguements

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates, django-sessions

basically i have two separate views, but i need form data from the first view to pass to the second view without having to pass it via URL parameters. is this possible? NOJS

Comment: Can you explain why you want to do this and provide your view code?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: hey! code wise i cant provide much since im more looking for the method on how to do it, but i can describe it better:
view 1: contains a template with a form in it
view 2: contains another template with a form in it, but that form requires view 1's form data

Comment: Maybe create a model called something like "tempModel" and add fields to it corresponding to the data that you need. Create an instance and save it in the back end then in your second view, call the instance that you just created and populate the fields with template tags. Does this sound like what your are looking to accomplish? You may have to create a user instance, if one does not already exist just so you have something to tie the temp data to. You can also delete the temp data if needed in view 2. If the data is pertinent to the user, then just add fields to the user instead of tempmodal